# Can not remove fragment from backstack using popBackStack() or remove()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, back-stack

I have 2 fragments: **SportsList** and **Workout**

I put **SportsList** fragment as this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack("SportsList").replace(R.id.fragment, sportsListFragment);
```

And then I put **Workout**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack("Workout").replace(R.id.fragment, workoutFragment);
```

I am using `replace()` method so **SportsList** should be removed, but when I call `popBackStackImmediate()` it remains there.

So I tried removing **SportsList** manually at **Workout** fragment, when I click a button. So I do this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment oldFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("SportsList");
fm.beginTransaction().remove(oldFragment).commit();
```

But this gives me following error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
>                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:770)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:541)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

I also tried to do this:

```
fm.popBackStack("SportsList", 0);
```

and this:

```
fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

and this:

```
fm.popBackStack("SportsList", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

But these are removing current fragment (**Workout** fragment) instead of **SportsList** fragment. I am out of ideas right now. Besides that:

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment, sportsListFragment);
```

still adding **SportsList** fragment to the backstack. How could this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
ft.addToBackStack("SportsList").replace(R.id.fragment, sportsListFragment).addToBackStack(null);
```